# Shopify Django/GAE API

Tags: django, api, google-app-engine, shopify

When attempting to set this up, I am encountering the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
import settings
File "/Users/Paul/Documents/shopifywarrantymanager/settings.py", line 7, in <module>
from djangoappengine.settings_base import *
File "/Users/Paul/Documents/shopifywarrantymanager/djangoappengine/settings_base.py",     line 6, in <module>
setup_env()
File "/Users/Paul/Documents/shopifywarrantymanager/djangoappengine/boot.py", line 64, in setup_env
setup_project()
File "/Users/Paul/Documents/shopifywarrantymanager/djangoappengine/boot.py", line 114, in setup_project
from .utils import have_appserver, on_production_server
File "/Users/Paul/Documents/shopifywarrantymanager/djangoappengine/utils.py", line 12, in <module>
appconfig, unused = dev_appserver.LoadAppConfig(PROJECT_DIR, {})
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I have not altered the files in any way other than adding my API key/shared secret, and changing the application name in 'app.yaml' to the one I registered with GAE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using an old version of `Djangoappengine`.

The method `LoadAppConfig` since SDK 1.6 [returns](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/search?q=LoadAppConfig&origq=LoadAppConfig&btnG=Search%20Trunk) a tuple of three values `(AppInfoExternal, URLMatcher, from_cache)`; the code in `utils.py` is wrong because is expecting just two values from it.

If you look into a [more updated version of Djangoappengine](https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine) you can see that the method is correctly called:

```
appconfig = dev_appserver.LoadAppConfig(PROJECT_DIR, 
                                        {},
                                        default_partition='dev')[0]
```